# More polite forms of "you"

Tags: synonyms, legalese

In French,  "vous" can be used instead of "toi" for this purpose. A seemingly rude example in English is when someone wants to instruct a lawyer, and writes 'I would like to instruct you.' I recognise the legal definition of 'to instruct', but this still sounds too forceful. What are  pleasant, but formal alternatives?

Comment: You presumably know that standard English abandoned the *formal/informal* possibilities of *you/thou* many generations ago. I find this question Unclear - are you really asking for *more polite forms of “you”* as in  the title, or are you simply asking for a different way to tell a lawyer that you want to engage his services? In which case, *why?* It's perfectly normal to tell a lawyer you want to instruct him, and your concept of ***instruct** still sounds too forceful* is simply a misunderstanding (perhaps based on translating from some equivalent *French* form?).

Comment: This may be an [interesting read](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9780/did-english-ever-have-a-formal-version-of-you) on ELU...

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's an unreasonable presumption. Why should a learner be aware of *thou*? It's perfectly reasonable to ask if English has different pronouns for expressing different degrees of respect when addressing someone; many other languages have them. The lawyer example is just that: *an example* asking about the appropriate way to form a polite, formal imperative. The only thing that's not clear here is whether *instruct* means *give instructions* or *engage services*, but in this case that doesn't make a difference to the answer.

Comment: At first I've read it like "More polite forms of Yo", which would be awesome.

Comment: @Esoteric: Check back over *this* OP's history of questions on ELL ([and ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/50720/lepressentiment)). He's a Francophone with very good command of English, and frankly it's inconceivable he's not intimately familiar with the *thee/you : tu/vous* "discrepancy" between the two languages.

Answer (score 11):

*I would like to instruct you* is both polite and formal. Modern English has no alternate pronoun forms to denote politeness, formality or etiquette; it's correct to translate both *tu* and *vous* (and their nominative forms as well; *you* serves both functions) as *you*.

Instead, in English we can use different verb constructions to show politeness, similar to using *vous + future tense* for polite requests in French. This is not strictly analogous to the differences between *tu* and *vous*, but it's the closest thing we have.

And you've constructed your sentence in the polite register already. *Would like* is the more polite and formal version of *want*, and generally in English politeness and formality go hand in hand. Here are two translations for comparison. Apologies for any errors in the French; mine is *extremely* rusty. I also suspect my translation of *instruct* (meaning *to issue a formal set of instructions*) is quite poor, since I'd be much more likely to translate *ordonner* as *order* rather than *instruct*, but my French vocabulary isn't so hot. Please feel free to edit and change *ordonner* to the correct verb.

> Je veux vous ordonner.
>   I would like to instruct you.
>
> Je veux toi ordonner.
>   I want to instruct you.

Additionally, *instruct* is quite formal, but not forceful. Synonyms in this case include *direct*, *order* and *command*. The latter two are decidedly less polite than *instruct*, because these are the forceful verbs in English. *Direct* is just as formal as *instruct* and a touch more polite, but it's also slightly vaguer. If you say *I would like to direct you*, it might be taken to mean something like *I want to guide you in a general direction* as opposed to *I want to give you instructions*; an *instruction* is more specific than *a direction*.

If you provide a bit more context on exactly what type of instructions are being given to the attorney, I can suggest more nuanced synonyms. For example, *[brief](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/brief_2)* may (or may not) be an appropriate choice here.

Comment: The verb choice also matters.  "I want to show you" is more common than "I want to teach you" or "I want to instruct you".  "I want to show you" is more polite in that it implies that the learner is just expected to watch; the choice of whether to learn is up to the learner.

Comment: Unfortunately, "instruct"'s legal meaning is very different from "show" or "teach".  The legal concept of "instruct" is dictatorial, so it is reasonable that LePressentiment picked up "rude" connotations -- even if the speaker did not intend to be rude.

Comment: I disagree that *show* is more polite and with your reasoning. When we say *I'll show you* to mean teaching, there's a definite implication that the observer needs to copy the exhibited form. It's not "up to the learner" in a way that *teach* is not (anyone can of course actively refuse to learn something regardless of whether it's *shown* or *taught*). The difference between *show* and *teach* is that *show* necessarily involves demonstration; *teach* may not. You're right that I've got the wrong sense of *instruct* though; I'll fix that.

Comment: What @Jasper said. Nothing in this answer addresses the highly context-specific sense of ***instruct = engage = hire** [a legal representative]*, which is not in any meaningful sense "forceful, rude".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with how Esoteric Screen Name rewrote his answer.  It matches my understanding of instruct = give directions [to a lawyer].

Comment: @Jasper: I don't really understand what there is to agree or disagree with here. Firstly, I've absolutely no idea what the *question* is (per my comment and associated closevote). Secondly, I can't see why it's necessary to write a whole answer pointing out to OP that there's nothing remotely unusual about telling a lawyer you'd like to instruct him, using exactly the words in OP's question text. In fact that's the *standard* phrasing for such a context, so why are we being asked for alternatives in the first place?

Comment: @FumbleFingers.  By "agree with [E.S.N.]", I meant that I thought his revised answer did address both "the sense of instruct" and the forcefulness/rudeness issues you mentioned in your earlier comment.  As for why the original poster asked for alternatives:  I expect that there are cultural issues.  The OP might have a different understanding of the relative status of a lawyer and his (or her) client, or might attach different connotations to "instruct" or "you".

Comment: The closest thing we currently have to a formal *you* are constructions like *your majesty*, *your excellency*, *your honor*, etc.  These are *extremely* formal and only appropriate when addressing people with specific official titles.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you seem to be forgetting that this is a site for people who are *learning* English. Yes, the original sentence was properly formed in this case, but the question made it clear that the OP didn't know it was correct, and so requested instruction and more appropriate alternatives. *In fact that's the standard phrasing for such a context* - yes, but *the OP didn't know that*.

Answer (score 2):

"You" is the polite form (equivalent to "vous").

The more familiar form (equivalent to "toi") is or was "thou", which is now archaic/obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

"You" is already the polite and formal form.
Simply put
You=Vous
Tu=Thou, a term no longer existing and replaced by "you".